# I want to store data in a ListView, the data is added dynamically

Tags: android, listview

I want to store data in a `ListView`, the data is added dynamically, I send the parameter for another `Activity` and always the `ListView` restart, how I can store the data?

This is my code

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cotizaciones);
    lvCotizacion = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista_cotizaciones);
    list_cotizaciones = new ArrayList<String>();
    obtenerNombre();
}

public void obtenerNombre(){
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    nombre = extras.getString("nombre");


    list_cotizaciones.add(nombre);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_cotizaciones);
    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lvCotizacion.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: create method in adapter to add item in `ArrayList` and do `notifyDatasetChanged()`

Comment: You wouldn't *store* the data in a ListView. You'd only *display* data in it. See @Nilesh's comment above on how to properly store data outside of the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom Adapter that extends BaseAdapter and implement its methods. Also include a method to add Data to your ArrayList:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
   ArrayList<String> data;
   public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> data)
   {
      this.data = data;
   }

   public void addString(String string)
   {
      data.add(string);
      notifyDataSetInvalidated(); //Reload ListView's data
   }

   //Fill in the required methods:
   public int getCount(){...}
   public Object getItem(int position){...}
   public long getItemId(int position){...}
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){...}
}
```